# How to use Selenium Webdriver in Java to get tag values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to use this code to make my experiment. I have tried to make a system to get the data from a website and use the lagrange interpolation method to create a polynomial. I am studying Selenium with Java to do this. Take a look at what I've developed.

```
package com.gustavo.seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class seleniumTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/gustavo/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    String valor;

    driver.get("http://cotacoes.economia.uol.com.br/acao/cotacoes-historicas.html?codigo=PETR4.SA&size=200&page=1&period=");
    valor = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='odd']")).getText();
    System.out.println(valor);
}
```

Note: I'm using linux and Firefox.

Comment: _...get the data..._ which data are you trying to extract exactly? Is creating/using _lagrange interpolation method to create a polynomial_ part of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your locator and if you want to fetch all the elements then you need to use `driver.findElements()` method.

Try the below XPath locator which will identify number of rows that table has:

```
String xPath = "//table[@id='tblInterday']/tbody//tr";
```

and you can get the size of the rows like this:

```
int rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath)).size();
```

and you can loop through whole rows using loops for example `for` loop like below:

```
for(int i=1;i<rows;i++) {

}
```

The below XPath will identity number of columns in each row based on the row index number:

```
String xPath = "//table[@id='tblInterday']/tbody//tr[row index number]/td";
```

As there are many rows, you can pass the row index to the above XPath like below:

```
for(int i=1;i<rows;i++) {
    driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+i+"]/td"));
}
```

As we are using the `driver.findElements()` method above, it will hold all the columns elements, we can loop through and print each of them like below:

```
for(WebElement element : driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+i+"]/td"))) {
    System.out.print(element.getText()+"\t");
}
```

Replace

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+i+"]/td")).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e.getText()+"\t"));
```

with

```
for(WebElement element : driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+i+"]/td"))) {
        System.out.print(element.getText()+"\t");
    }
```

If you want to print normally.

Below is the whole code using Java 8 :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://cotacoes.economia.uol.com.br/acao/cotacoes-historicas.html?codigo=PETR4.SA&size=200&page=1&period=");
        String xPath = "//table[@id='tblInterday']/tbody//tr";
        int rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath)).size();
        for(int i=1;i<rows;i++) {
            driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+i+"]/td")).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e.getText()+"\t"));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Post the element in the DOM(the whole thing between the tags).

Your code will work if it's a text inside the tag but if the text is inside a value parameter for example, you will need to getProperty("value") in order to extract it from the element.